# How to include private contructor in Line Coverage?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, cobertura, jmockit

I am using jmockit to mock my classes for unit test purpose. Everything is working fine so far.

I have a factory which is thread safe and singleton as shown below:

So for below class, I am able to get 50% Line Coverage because I am not able to cover private constructor `TestFactory()`.

```
public class TestFactory {

    // not able to cover this
    private TestFactory() {}

    private static class TestHolder {
        private static final TestClient INSTANCE = new TestClient();
    }

    public static IClient getInstance() {
        return TestHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

My question is - Is there any way  I can cover `TestFactory()` private constructor so that I can get 100% Line Coverage in my Cobertura Report for this class?

Comment: Why do you need to mock it? If you create an instance of the Singleton and check that it is not null, (and that you always get the same), that should cover the requirements. There is more that just that one hammer in your toolbox.

Comment: I just need to cover that piece of code so that I can get 100% line coverage in my cobertura report. I think, I do not need to mock it, I just need to find a way so that I can cover that piece of code.

Comment: Just create the singleton using the intended way, and you will cover the private constructor. Actually this is easier if you do it the other way around : only write a line of code when you have a failing test. Then your code is 100% covered by construction.

Comment: I have created singleton normal way and I don't see it is covering private constructor at all. `TestFactory.getInstance()`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, :-(. I have not had enough coffee yet. I had not seen it was the constructor for TestClient which was called instead of TestFactory. Now on the other hand, there is nothing in the constructor and you can't call it. Why does it exist at all? What would happen if you simply delete the constructor?

Comment: @PeterTillemans That's what Singleton is all about. We cannot delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke it using reflection or just `mockit.Deencapsulation.newInstance()`. Write a test method like this

```
@Test
public void privateConstructorCoverage() throws Exception {
   Deencapsulation.newInstance(TestFactory.class);
}
```

[Deencapsulation javadoc](https://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1267/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Deencapsulation.html)

> Provides utility methods that enable access to (ie "de-encapsulate") otherwise non-accessible fields, methods and constructors belonging to code under test.